# TypeScript: Exporting node.js function with static attributes

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have the following code working with Node.js:

```
// myModule.js
// Declaring module myModule with exports
exports.myFunction = function () {
        //... do stuff
};
exports.myFunction.staticAttribute = 'some value';

#######################################################

// test.js
// Using the module
var test = require('./myModule');

console.log(test.myFunction.staticAttribute);
```

I am trying to write the same code in TypeScript but it is not working:

```
// myModule.ts
// Declaring module myModule with exports
export function myFunction() {
    //... do stuff
};

export var myFunction.staticAttribute = 'some value';
```

It says  **`Expected ';'`** right after **`export var myFunction`** so basicaly instead of the **`.meta`**

Comment: I don't think you should have `var` in this line.

Comment: i think @dystroy is right. change last line like that : exports.myFunction.staticAttribute = 'some value';

Comment: no sorry i dont know typescript. missed that tag

Answer (score 0):

You’re already exporting `myFunction`, so put the property on the function if you want it to be there.

```ts
// myModule.ts
// Declaring module myModule with exports
export function myFunction() {
    //... do stuff
}

myFunction['staticAttribute'] = 'some value';
```

Note that you can’t use dot-accessor to attach arbitrary properties, and you’re defeating typing by doing the above.

It’s possible to export instead as a variable with correct typing for the extra static property:

```ts
// myModule.ts
// Declaring module myModule with exports
export var myFunction:{ ():void; staticAttribute?:string; } = function () {
    //... do stuff
};

myFunction.staticAttribute = 'some value';
```